# Is it possible to construct monotonically increasing or decreasing subsequence from any sequence of function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

In case of sequence of numbers we can always construct subsequence which is monotonically increasing or decreasing.

Is this true in case of sequence of function (here monotonically in point wise sense )

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any sequence of distinct points $(x_n)$ and define $f_n(x)$ to be the characteristic function of the singleton  set  $\{x_n\}$.  Note that $\chi_{\{x\}} \leq \chi_{\{y\}}$ cannot hold unless $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $
f_n(x)=(x-n)\sin(x-n)$. Then, for any pair $(n_1,n_2)$ fixed, there are infinitely many points $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$
f_{n_1}(x)\geq f_{n_2}(x) \quad \hbox{and} \quad f_{n_1}(y)\leq f_{n_2}(y).
$$
However, what is true is that if you fix a $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then there always exists an increasing sequence (basically because this reduces to the number sequence case). But you cannot ask for an increasing subsequence of functions, where you want to have monotonicity for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ simultaneously.

Comment: Or $f_n(x)=nx$.

Comment: @bof much cooler hahaha